# Removing noexcept from a C++ function, how to deal with the noexcept functions that call it?

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring, automated-refactoring, noexcept

Suppose I have a `foo` function marked as `noexcept` somewhere in my code. Many other functions call `foo`, and many of them are also marked as `noexcept`.

Now suppose I have to adjust `foo`, and now it can throw an exception, so it's not `noexcept` anymore.

1. All the functions that call `foo` must have the `noexcept` removed, is this correct?
2. How am I suppose to find all those functions that call `foo`? Is there a better way than ordinary searching with my text editor?

Comment: 1: Only if they don't handle the exception themselves.  2: Use an IDE

Comment: 1. *...handle the exceptions themselves* _or_ are happy to be terminated.  2. *Use an IDE* _or_ comment out the function and see what breaks - there are your callers (assuming no overloads / conversions etc allow it to compile).

Comment: @TonyDelroy *comment out the function and see what breaks* -- hey, that's one hell of a tip. Thank you.

Comment: Note that "comment out the function and see what breaks" is not a reliable way to find call sites in the presence of overloading, since callers may still compile by resolving to the second-best match.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yep, you're right. In addition to comment it out, I'm also using the features Visual C++ offers.

Comment: Visual Studio's Code Analysis tool will tell you if you're calling a non-`noexcept` function from a `noexcept` function.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I did note that.

Answer (score 0):

1. From searching on the spec, it seems that functions that call potentially-throwing functions, can in fact have the noexcept specifier. If an exception is thrown by `foo` and it's being called by another function which is marked as `noexcept`, then the exception will cause [`std::terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) to be called. So depending on if you want the exception to be propagated or not, you needn't remove all the `noexcept` specifiers. However, if you want the exception to be propagated then you probably do need to remove these `noexcept` specifiers.
2. Off the top of my head, I think the best method would be searching using a text editor, although, perhaps someone else has a better method for refactoring. Also, an IDE can definitely handle major refactoring with ease.